# Is access to the Google Analytics Realtime Reporting API (via javascript) handled similarly to the Core Reporting API or is it dramatically different?

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-analytics-api

I'm using the 'Hello Analytics' code example found at [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js][1] to allow me to gain access to my Google Analytics account and log the JSON response to the console.  I can traverse the JSON and see how to request specific data I want from the Core Reporting API... Its pretty awesome.

I'm more interested in the realtime data, however. For this particular project I need something faster than the core reporting API...

Questions:  Is the Realtime Reporting API something that is accessible via javascript and if so, would it (generally speaking) also work in this same fashion?   Meaning Is it just a matter of changing EITHER of the following to get the same type of response from the REALTIME api?

```
// Set authorized scope.
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];
```

or

```
// Load the Google Analytics client library.
gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {
```

I see a good number of resources / examples for the core reporting API, but not much on the realtime API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) and the [Real time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) work very much the same way, with the same authentication scopes even.

### Core Reporting API call

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get(...)
```

[Core Reporting API method reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference).

### Real time API call

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.realtime.get(...)
```

[Realtime API method reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get).

The Realtime API has is its own set of dimensions and metrics that begin with `rt:...` where the Core reporting API dimensions and metrics begin with `ga:...`.

Answer (score 0):

I use both of them in my Google Apps Script. These identical functions may help to understand the similarity.

**in Core Reporting API** Function below gives users, sessions, avgSessionDuration and uniqueEvents for given dimensions with given filters.

```
function countClicks(analyticsID,startDate,endDate){
  try {
    var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      'ga:'+analyticsID,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:uniqueEvents',
      {'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel','filters': 'ga:sessionDuration>1;ga:eventCategory=@'+SUBJECT}).rows;
    return results;
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
    logTable.appendRow([e["stack"],e.message,new Date()]);
  }
}
```

**in Realtime API** This gives me number of active users at given dimensions

```
function countClicks(analyticsID){
  try {
    var results = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get(
      'ga:'+analyticsID,
      'rt:activeUsers',
      {'dimensions':'rt:country,rt:city,rt:eventCategory,rt:eventAction,rt:eventLabel,rt:operatingSystem,rt:deviceCategory'}).rows;
    return results;
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
    logTable.appendRow([e["stack"],e.message,new Date()]);
  }
}
```

So, yes. It almost works as the same fashion.

There are more metric and dimension options in [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#metrics) acording to [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets)